# Find no of reducers from job log

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In mapreduce, I want to find the number of mappers and reducers from the program log.

As input I am passing three files to the program and explicitly setting the number of reducers to 5 ( just for testing purposes ).

Program :

```
public class WordCount {

 public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
 } 

 public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            //System.out.println(key + "  " + val.get());
            sum += val.get();
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(5);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
 }

}
```

Log :

```
2015-11-08 11:40:48,749 INFO  mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1384)) - Job job_local1769091332_0001 completed successfully
2015-11-08 11:40:48,829 INFO  mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1391)) - Counters: 38
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=20931
        FILE: Number of bytes written=2179872
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=1287
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=194
        HDFS: Number of read operations=119
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=38
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=14
        Map output records=35
        Map output bytes=319
        Map output materialized bytes=479
        Input split bytes=353
        Combine input records=0
        Combine output records=0
        Reduce input groups=12
        Reduce shuffle bytes=479
        Reduce input records=35
        Reduce output records=12
        Spilled Records=70
        Shuffled Maps =15
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=15
        GC time elapsed (ms)=272
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=1578663936
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=183
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=86
```

Answer (score 0):

In output log, you can see when a job starts number of splits based on the input size which is equal to the number of mappers.

For reducers, below are the ways to get number:
 1.number of unique keys from the mapper output. 
 2.number of reducer output files generated 
 3.From web interface also, you can get the number.

From output log, you get inner details like number of records at every stage, and combiner things, read and write operations, bytes etc

Answer (score 0):

In hadoop 2.0 there are two predefined Job counters:

```
TOTAL_LAUNCHED_MAPS : The number of map tasks that were launched.
TOTAL_LAUNCHED_REDUCES : The number of reduce tasks that were launched.
```

From the Hadoop CLI, typing `mapred job -counter <job_id>` should print out the above described counters that describes the number of map and reduce tasks that were launched for the job.